# Magento Bundled Product showing only One product however i have Two at backend

Tags: php, mysql, magento

All my products that are bundle type  are showing only first product however i can clearly see them visible on the backend . There are two bundled items there from admin side .

I change the database to my old few days backup its now showing . But what could be wrong current one .

I flushed cache reindex data but still same

All items are radio type

Comment: Is second product accessible directly on front end?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that status of each product is 'enabled' and visibility is 'catalog, search' and that you have selected a store on the 'websites' tab of the product if you are using multiple store config.

Comment: Have u checked the stock of your both items.? is both items individually also appears on front-end??

Comment: yes they are in stock . and this not only happens with one bundle products but all bundle products

Comment: are u using multi website??